# Why do I got "conda: command not found" when building a docker, while in base image the "conda" command works fine?

Tags: python, bash, docker, conda

I am trying to build a docker from a base image, the Dockerfile is like this:

```sh
FROM my/base/image:latest
RUN conda install package-name
RUN rm -rf /tmp/*
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

and I got "conda: command not found". But if I directly run the base image as a container, the conda command works fine.
Also, if I add `RUN source ~/.bashrc` in the Dockerfile, when building process run into this line, it will enter another terminal and will not response to any command. What‘s happening in this situation? I would be very grateful if anyone could give me any advice and suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add some useful information: in the base image, no need to run "source ~/.bashrc", I can directly use "conda" command

Comment: Maybe try `CMD ["/bin/bash", "-l"]`

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bashrc` is sourced by interactive shells, it's the reason why it works when you use it from within the container. This is not the case for a `Dockerfile` during the build process.

In the [conda docker image](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/blob/b87a07feac7e8b14244eb7697771af5003c53aab/miniconda3/debian/Dockerfile#L25), the `conda` executable is simply added to the `PATH`.

```
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH
```

It's a simple solution. You can also call `/opt/conda/bin/conda install ...` (to adapt according to your conda installation) if you do not want to alter the `PATH`.

#### Alternative

If you want to have `~/.bashrc` sourced you can use the [`SHELL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell) instruction to override the default shell used for commands with a bash interactive shell (thanks to the `i` flag).

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-i", "-c"] 
RUN conda install ...
```

However it seems to be a less conventional approach.